# Error while importing contact in mobile connect

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect

When I try to import below csv file via Import Contacts of MobileConnect, I get this error in UI.

```
An error occurred attempting to save your new list build. Contact Global Support for additional assistance regarding this error.
```

When I view DevTools, I see this error

```
Import Definition is Invalid: Select the appropriate destination for a Destination Type of Contacts
```

CSV file content is this

```
SubscriberKey,MobileNumber,FirstName,LastName,City,State,Status,Locale,ZipCode
447537120834_1,447537120834,Amit,Singh,Manchester,Britain,,gb,UK12345
```

[or]

```
City,Contact Key,First Name,Last Name,Locale,Mobile Number,State,Zip Code
Manchester,447537120834_1,Dummy,User,GB,447537120834,Britain,UK12345
```

Is my CSV file not in right format?

Comment: Are you trying to import under Mobile Connect -> Manage Contacts -> Create -> Import File or is it the Import mobile contacts activity in Automation Studio?

Comment: I'm trying it from Mobile connect and not in automation studio.